# Finding an expat relative/friendly forum for the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, job-hunting, accommodation, cost-of-living

As far as I can understand, this stack is about posting questions relevant to bureaucracy issues and other technicalities.

I am looking for other types of advice though. To be exact, I am looking to migrate to Britain but would like to get advice on which town to choose, different "dos and don'ts", advice on how to efficiently one can find a reasonably priced apartment, student friendly areas, etc....

Which I think is out of the scope of this stack.

So could anybody introduce me to a forum that would have people that may be able to help me out by giving their two cents or guide me on that particular subject?

Comment: Those topics are indeed within the scope of this site; the problem is how to create more objective questions (to avoid the dreaded "opinion-based" close reason) that will nonetheless elicit the information you seek.  If you're looking for a more open-ended discussion, then you are right that another site would be better for that.

Comment: @ouflak Do you have any such site in mind? a preliminary googlesearch yielded only blogs  and websites.. I just want to post on a forum to discuss cost of living "survival strategies" for the first month compare cities for their student friendliness ease of finding a job average salaries places to look for jobs locally, average rent to average salary ratios, get useful links or references on that etc. I am afraid that if I make such a post here It will get on hold like within 5 minutes. I really didn't expect this post not to get blocked as well to be honest :P

Comment: I think you meant to aim your question at phoog, but I'm active on immigrationboards. com. There are a variety of expat sites around. Mileage may vary and sometimes it's just a bit of luck as to whether you really kick off a discussion or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot m8 Im going to check out immigrationboardscom soon but I couldnt find that phoog one.. is it suppose to stand for something related to exchange ? cause I cant find any forum by that name and phog seems to be a relevant site but its for students in america as far as I could tell.. am I missing something? :P